# Solve in $\mathbb{R}$: $(x^2-3x-2)^2-3(x^2-3x-2)-2-x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Solve in $\mathbb{R}$: $(x^2-3x-2)^2-3(x^2-3x-2)-2-x=0$

I'm supposed to solve this equation. It's from a math contest so solving it by hand would be preferable (no quartic formulas).
I thought about making $u = x^2-3x-2$ obviously but it leads to another quartic equation. 
I also tried the substitution $u=x+2$, and after the whole expand trinomial, simplify, invoke rational root theorem and test roots, I still got nothing out of it.

I noticed that $x^2-3x-2$ can't be factored nicely so I dunno what other route to take. Lots of equations I tackled in math contests could make use of nice trigonometric substitutions, but none in particular pop in my head right now.

If anyone can give me hints or a full solution, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Is the math contest this problem was taken from already finished?  Or is it still on-going?

Comment: So $f(f(x))=x$, interesting.

Comment: Try solving $f(x) = x$ with $f(x) = x^2 -3x -2$. What is $f(f(x))$ then equals?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche This is a strange question. I don't think that if I was cheating I'd admit it. Anyway it's from a pretty old contest: http://www.obm.org.br/export/sites/default/revista_eureka/docs/eureka10.pdf page 49, problem 74.

Comment: I've seen this exact problem a several years ago. So, if it is from an ongoing contest, then that contest is using problems from old sources.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone Please don't take offense at Joel's question--I've seen a lot of live contest problems asked on this site, and quite a few people freely admit they're asking for help on them.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you.  Next time, please indicate in the original post the explicit reference to the contest (as you just did now in a comment) so that future readers will be more likely to help you.

Comment: It's fine, I understand the concern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have a quartic, there are potentially 4 real solutions.

Note that any solution to $x = x^2 - 3x - 2$ is also a solution to the given equation.

Hence, $x^2 - 4x - 2$ is a factor of the quartic. Now find the other factor, and solve both quadratics.

Alternatively, see [this almost 10 year old thread](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=151&t=18184) on the Art of Problem Solving Forum, or this [slightly newer thread](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=401524) which discusses a similar problem.

Comment: +1 This is an extremely good answer.  I wish more people on this site would answer like this.

Comment: I don't understand why the second line is true, could you give some more detail? blue's comment notes that $f(x)=x^2-3x-2\Rightarrow f(f(x))=x$, something that I didn't notice the first time. Are you using this fact to deduce the second line? I think I'm missing something completely obvious...

Comment: If $x = x^2-3x-2$, then substitute $x^2-3x-2$ for $x$ on the right side to get $x = (x^2-3x-2)^2-3(x^2-3x-2)-2$, which is the given equation. Hence, the solutions to $x = x^2-3x-2$ are also solutions to the given equation.

Comment: Oh! I just stared at this, confused, for 5 minutes or so. Normally I substitute $y=f(x)$ but I had to think a little more to get the $x=f(x)$ substitution. I understand it now, and I can finish the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: (Also, thanks for taking the time to find these threads. Lots of insightful answers.)